# Steady states stability numerical analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-theory

I have a non-linear ordinary differential equation system of dimension 4. I have found one steady state of interest for this system and I would like to test numerically the stability of this steady state. Analytically the Jacobian would be very large, thereby I am looking for a numerical way to study the stability of steady states for such system of ODE. Do you know if there exists such a numerical method ?

Thank you.

Comment: In similar situations I did the following. So, you pick any computer algebra system that you like that is capable of doing symbolic differentiation (Maple, SymPy+NumPy, MATLAB, Mathematica, ... ). Then you can find analytic formula for Jacobi matrix, then plug your equilibria coordinates and get a numeric matrix. Then you just use any algorithm that finds you eigenvalues of this matrix. This gives you a rough idea if the equilibrium is stable or not. The only caveat is when eigenvalues are quite close to zero, but it is always a problem no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the case of a system of 2 dimensions, the stability of the steady states can indeed be characterized when knowing the eigenvalues. Yet is there a generalization for such steady states characterization with regards to eigenvalues when the dimension is equal to 4 ?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is mentioned in almost any text on nonlinear dynamics or dynamical systems. If **all** eigenvalues have strictly negative real parts, then your equilibrium is stable. If there is **at least one** eigenvalue with strictly positive real part, the equilibrium is unstable. The question becomes difficult when you have eigenvalues with zero real part and that is a subject of so called "center manifold theory".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to do as you suggested and I have two cases :
First case : $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3 = 0$ and  $\lambda_2 = \lambda_4 > 0$.
Second case : $\lambda_1 < 0 $ ;  $\lambda_2 > 0 $ ; $ \lambda_3 = 0$ and  $\lambda_4 > 0$.
According to your message, these two cases are in the scope of the center manifold theory. Is there a way to have informations on the stability in the two cases ?

Comment: In this case equilibria are unstable: even if you have eigenvalues with zero real part, you also have eigenvalues with positive real part. No matter what, they imply that the equilibrium is unstable. I have written that poorly in previous comment. The better version is the following. If you have at least one eigenvalue with positive real part, no matter what are others, the equilibrium is unstable. The hard case is when you have only eigenvalues with ${\mathrm Re}\, z \leqslant 0$. And it really requires [center manifold theory](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Center_manifold#Main_Results)